# How to setup a background image on a tk.TopLevel()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

I'm trying to add a background to a tk.TopLevel() window.

I have succeeded using the same code as follows to add a bakground to a tk.Tk(). However, the same code doesn't work and leaves me with the default background.

```py
def add_window_launching():
    #initializing window
    add_window=tk.Toplevel()
    add_window.title("Inventaire Petits Débrouillards")
    add_window.geometry('900x350')
    add_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    #Setting background
    raw_image=Image.open("C:/Users/Ordinateur/Desktop/db-update-petits-debrouillards/UI/ajout.png")
    background_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(raw_image)
    background_label = tk.Label(add_window, image=background_image)

    #Adding widgets
    welcome_text=tk.Label(add_window, text="Text")
    object_description=tk.Label(add_window, text="Description de l'objet :")
    description_entry=tk.Entry(add_window, width=100)
    row=SQL.Entries([description_entry], add_window)
    submit_button=tk.Button(add_window, text="Ajouter", command=row.adding_entry)

    #Organizing window
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    welcome_text.place(anchor="n", relx=0.5, rely=0.25)
    object_description.place(anchor="nw", relx=0.08, rely=0.5)
    description_entry.place(anchor="ne", relx=0.92, rely=0.5)
    submit_button.place(anchor="n", relx=0.5, rely=0.75)
```

Here is the result of the execution of the script. Top window is the main window, bottom window is the TopLevel one. Backgrounds must be identic.
I can't post images because my account is new but you'll find the result i got [here](https://i.postimg.cc/XNCQHmKw/Screen-Shot004.png).
Any ideas why it doesn't work ?

Comment: [Keep a reference to your image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug in `PhotoImage`.

`Garbage Collector` removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable in function and then you can't see image.

You have to assign image to global variable or to some widget. It is popular to assign to `Label` which displays this image:

```
 background_label.image = background_image
```

Doc: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)